# My unity game fps drop on iPhone 13 when game focused out, How can I Fix That?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I have created 2d game with unity.

In my game I have too many animation is that so I need to fix game fps to 60 with this code:

**Application.targetFrameRate = 60;**

Its working very good in android devices but in iOS there is some problems.

On iPhone game is starting with 60 fps and its working like android until iOS interrupt from anything like brightness change during game, any notification came up or I minimize game then start again fps drop on 40 and its newer get back to 60. Can I fix that somehow or should I optimize my game for 40fps.

Comment: Have you considered reapplying the setting?

Comment: Yes i tried that too but it didnt work either. I ran script on every focus then i tried to run script on every seconds but it did not work